# Typescript: how to assign value to Element.scrollIntoView's parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was trying to make a method to use "scrollIntoView" and optionally set its parameters, but when trying to set the `block` parameter, it says:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ScrollLogicalPosition | undefined'.
```

And when trying to set `behaviour` gives:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ScrollBehavior | undefined'
```

Here is code:

```
scrollToFirstElementOfClassName(className: string, blockValue: string = "center",behavior: string = 'smooth') {

    const elms = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

      elms[0].scrollIntoView({
        block: blockValue,
        behavior: behavior
      });
    
  }
```

So "ScrollLogicalPosition" and "ScrollBehavior" are types? So I ned to convert the string to those types in some way(?)

Comment: `blockValue`'s type should be `ScrollLogicalPosition`. It is complaining because `ScrollLogicalPosition` is a set of string literals that can be used, while `blockValue` is any string. `string` is not assignable to the set of strings that make up `ScrollLogicalPosition`, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is saying your provided type `string` is wider than the intended Union type of string literal, and thus would lead to un-type-safety.

More specifically, your `blockValue` has the correct value, but Typescript wants its type to be `ScrollLogicalPosition`, which is a union/subset of string, but not actually string.

I believe a fix is changing the type of your function parameters:

```
scrollToFirstElementOfClassName(className: string, blockValue: ScrollLogicalPosition = "center", behavior: ScrollBehavior = 'smooth') {

    const elms = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

      elms[0].scrollIntoView({
        block: blockValue,
        behavior: behavior
      });
    
  }
```